# How to define a sequence with an infinite amount of each natural number?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I was trying to create a sequence such that for every $x \in \mathbb{N}$, that sequence has a subsequence that converges to $x$. 
Basically I came up with the sequence that has each natural number an infinite amount of times. Now I am having trouble defining it. Any help?

Comment: I take it that you have one in mind and are simply having trouble defining it carefully. Can you describe informally the particular one that you found?

Comment: It's the one below. 1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sequence is straightforward enough that unless you have to produce an algorithm, a simple verbal description is the best approach if you want something more detailed than a simple illustration of the sequence, as in **ASKASK**’s answer. You could, for instance, say something like this:

> We’ll define the sequence in blocks. The first block has one term, $1$. The second block has two terms, $1$ and $2$ in that order. And in general for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ the $k$-th block consists of the integers $1$ through $k$ in that order. Thus, the sequence is $$\langle 1,\color{red}{1,2},1,2,3,\color{red}{1,2,3,4},1,2,3,4,5,\color{red}1\ldots\rangle\;,$$ where I’ve colored the blocks alternately black and red to make them stand out.

This is a perfectly clear description of the sequence. If you want an algorithm that outputs $a_n$ when you input $n$, you have to work a lot harder. Here’s one way to dig one out.

Things are a little simpler if we index the terms starting with $0$, so that $a_0=1$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, $a_3=1$, and so on. Now look at the values of $n$ for which $a_n=1$: $0,1,3,6,10,15,\ldots\;$. These are the indices at which the successive blocks begin. The first block is just $a_0$; the second is $a_1,a_2$; the third is $a_3,a_4,a_5$; and so on.

If you think about it a bit, it should be clear that these numbers are just the sums of consecutive integers: $0$, $0+1=1$, $0+1+2=3$, etc. You may know the formula for such sums:

$$0+1+2+\ldots+k=\frac12k(k+1)\;;$$

call this number $t_k$. The $k$ terms $a_{t_{k-1}},a_{t_{k-1}+1},\ldots,a_{t_k-1}$ make up the $k$-th block, which looks like $1,2,\ldots,k$. Thus, if $t_{k-1}\le n<t_k$, then $a_n=n-t_{k-1}+1$. In order to express $a_n$ in terms of $n$, therefore, we just need to figure out how to express $k$ in terms of $n$.

Now $t_{k-1}\le n<t_k$ if and only if

$$\frac12k(k-1)\le n<\frac12k(k+1)\,$$

i.e.,

$$k^2-k\le 2n<k^2+k\;.$$

We can complete the squares to write this as

$$\left(k-\frac12\right)^2-\frac14\le 2n<\left(k+\frac12\right)^2-\frac14$$

and hence

$$k-\frac12\le\sqrt{2n+\frac14}<k+\frac12\;.$$

Solving for $k$, we find that

$$\sqrt{2n+\frac14}-\frac12<k\le\sqrt{2n+\frac14}+\frac12\;,$$

which says that $k$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $\sqrt{2n+\frac14}+\frac12$:

$$k=\left\lfloor\sqrt{2n+\frac14}+\frac12\right\rfloor\;.\tag{1}$$

Summing up, for any non-negative integer $n$ we have $t_{k-1}\le n<t_k$ precisely when $k$ is given by the formula $(1)$, and then we have

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=n-t_{k-1}+1\\
&=n-\frac12\left\lfloor\sqrt{2n+\frac14}+\frac12\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt{2n+\frac14}+\frac12\right\rfloor-1\right)+1\\
&=n-\frac12\left\lfloor\sqrt{2n+\frac14}+\frac12\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lfloor\sqrt{2n+\frac14}-\frac12\right\rfloor+1
\end{align*}$$

As a quick sanity check, this says that

$$\begin{align*}
a_9&=9-\frac12\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{73}4}+\frac12\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{73}4}-\frac12\right\rfloor+1\\
&=10-\frac12\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{73}+1}2\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{73}-1}2\right\rfloor\\
&=10-\frac12\cdot4\cdot3\\
&=4\;,
\end{align*}$$

which is indeed correct.

Comment: Looking at the complexity of what you did, I think it's safe to say that's not expected of me. But just so I can learn I will give it a thorough read. Thank you!!

Comment: @Chubbles: You’re welcome! I really do think that something like the highlighted description should be more than adequate for most purposes, but thought that you might like to see how an actual formula could be derived.

Answer (score 4):

How about just:

$$ a_n=1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$$

Clearly each natural number appears an infinite amount of times, so you can extract a subsequence converging to whichever natural number you want.

Comment: That's basically what I had in mind but I don't know how to properly define it. Something like 1 to n, 1 to n+1?

Answer (score 0):

One general way to create a sequence with an infinite number of accumulation points
 is to write a table of your sequence and read it by anti-diagonals. An intuitive way of looking at your problem is to write down the sequence in this form:

$$
1,\\
1,2,\\
1,2,3,\\
1,2,3,4,\\
\vdots \vdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

How about the sequence of disks you move in the Tower of Hanoi puzzle?

1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 ...

$a_n = k$ when n is $2^{k-1}$ times an odd number.